how to stop using a command directly
It is related to my old question. The problem is that both \usevar{bb} and \bb could work. Considering the command like \bb may be easily confused with a command that prifexed with \, I want to disable it and only use \usevar{} instead . Is there any way to do it ?
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\eqdef#1{\eqdefA#1,,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{\fpeval{#2}}}
\def\usevar#1{\csname #1\endcsname}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=12+21,cc=33,dd=44}

\usevar{bb}

\bb

\end{document}


I wouldn't use that code. It seems slick, but has several problems, the main one being that it unconditionally overrides existing commands.

Yes. I just use it for experimental purpose.

why are you worried about that? what's the conflict exactly? as @egreg says, you are overwriting standard commands because you do no checks and use names which are likely to conflict. but why is the fact you can use either \usevar{bb} or \bb a problem? all \usevar{bb} does is construct and use \bb. so there's an extra step there, but that's all. are you relying on that extra expansion step being there?

thanks ,  I need to think about it .

why is this tagged primitives?

I thought it was written with Tex . I've changed the tag.

The problem is that in TeX/LaTeX with macros there is no type management, so you cannot reliably detect the purpose of a defined macro. I. e., in TeX/LaTeX you cannot reliably detect

whether it is the case that the purpose of a defined macro is serving as variable whereby the tokens coming from top-level-expanding the macro form the value of the variable
or whether it is the case that a defined macro serves whatsoever other purpose.

Probably the actual matter of concern is avoiding the overriding of a control sequence token that is already defined when declaring a new variable or when assigning a new value to a variable.
If you like, you can use \ExpandArgs and \UseName for defining and calling macros within your own name space in terms of \newcommand* or \NewExpandableDocumentCommand or whatever defining-command that raises an error-message or a warning-message when being about to override a control sequence token that is already defined.
\UseName{exp_args_generate:n}{Nce}%
\newcommand*\eqdef[1]{\eqdefA#1,,}%
\UseName{@ifdefinable}\eqdefA{%
  \def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}%
}%
\UseName{@ifdefinable}\eqdefB{%
  \def\eqdefB#1=#2,{%
    \ExpandArgs{Nce}\newcommand*{MyNameSpace#1}{\fpeval{#2}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand*\usevar[1]{\UseName{MyNameSpace#1}}%
\newcommand*\showvar[1]{\ExpandArgs{c}\show{MyNameSpace#1}}%


\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=12+21,cc=33,dd=44}

\showvar{bb}

\show\MyNameSpacebb

\usevar{bb}

\MyNameSpacebb

\end{document}

This example is given for showing how expansion could be handled when defining the macro when the tokens forming key and value of a key=value-pair are already gathered and accessible as macro arguments.
For real life scenarios, where input of users is unpredictable, using a more evolved key=value-parser

which handles space tokens surrounding key=value-pairs or surrounding keys and/or values,
where the stripping of curly braces {..}, if present, is predictable,
where the case of the value being omitted or the = of s.th. that should be a key=value-pair being missing is handled,

is recommended for gathering keys and values with the elements of a comma separated list of key=value-pairs whose components might be surrounded by space tokens and/or might be nested in pairs of matching curly braces {...}.
You might be interested in expl3's \keyval_parse:NNn or in the package expkv-cs or in recent LaTeX 2ε's ltkeys.dtx or in the other packages related to the topic "Key-Val " that are listed on CTAN.

Use a higher level coding and a namespace, in this case a prefix \g_xcn_eqdef_
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqdef}{m}
 {
  \keyval_parse:NNn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n \xcn_eqdef_def:nn {#1}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n
 {
  \msg_error:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value } {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_def:nn
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist } {#1}
   }
   {
    \tl_new:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   }
  \tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } { \fp_eval:n {#2} }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value }
 { Missing~value~for~the~variable~#1 }
 { You~must~supply~a~value~for~the~variable~#1 }
\msg_new:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist }
 { Overriding~value~for~the~variable~#1 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\eqdef{aa=11,bb = 12+21 , cc= 33,dd=44,ff,aa=13}

\begin{document}

$\fpeval{\usevar{aa}+\usevar{bb}-\usevar{cc}*\usevar{dd}}$

$\fpeval{13+12+21-33*44}$

\end{document}

Output on the console
! Package xcn/eqdef Error: Missing value for the variable ff

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.39 ...{aa=11,bb = 12+21 , cc= 33,dd=44,ff,aa=13}

? h

You must supply a value for the variable ff

Package xcn/eqdef Warning: Overriding value for the variable aa

The missing value for ff triggers an error, while the second assignment to aa issues a warning.
Printed output


thanks @egreg. This example is concise and useful in calculation.

There is simple solution of your problem. Use control sequences \xcn:var:aa, \xcn:var:bb etc. instead \aa, \bb. These control sequences aren't defined in common TeX formats because a user cannot simply use them (the colon inside their names is a little complication). So, you can do a small modification of your code:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\eqdef#1{\eqdefA#1,,}
\def\eqdefA#1,{\ifx^#1^\else \eqdefB#1,\expandafter\eqdefA\fi}
\def\eqdefB#1=#2,{\expandafter\edef\csname xcn:var:#1\endcsname{\fpeval{#2}}}
\def\usevar#1{\csname xcn:var:#1\endcsname}

\eqdef{aa=11,bb=12+21,cc=33,dd=44}

\usevar{bb}

\bb

\end{document}

